# Network tab at chrome dev tools doesn't show requests send to server

Tags: axios, next.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new to nextjs, I'm trying to send data to server - with axios - I got the response correct, but I don't see the data send with POST request at network dev tools at chrome. Is there anyway I can see the requests of my application.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that All or Fetch/XHR are selected on the network tab. It should look something like this. You should be able to see your requests provided they are sending.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try following the steps:

1. Is your network recorder on? If not make sure to turn it on.
   [chrome dev image showing network recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EB06.png)
2. make sure filter and search fields is clear
3. fetch/xhr is selected

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have blocked requests checked. So verify the following,

1. All or Fetch/XHR is selected
2. Record Network is ON (Left Red icon with clear icon)
3. Blocked Requests in unchecked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Browser dev tools` network tab shows only client requests(`react.js` is a `client` library and all requests are made from `client`). In `next.js` you make requests from `server`(and it is good if you don't see requests in your `browser`, it means your requests are not duplicated from `server` and `client`). To inspect your requests on `server` you need to log(you can use libraries or simple `console.log`).